# Excel copy(Destination:=) failed in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I'm using copy(Destination:=) and would like to copy whole records in one excel to another excel file but failed to execute. Could it because of need to use range? Because there is not necessary to use range as i would like to copy all and paste into another excel file

```
oWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy(Destination:=oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A" & oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1))
```

It mentioned error as  below.

> "Copy method of Range class failed".

My Previous code are as below

```
oWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy()
oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A" & oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1).Select()
oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Paste
```

and it keep occur error message "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Paste method of Worksheet class failed" and despite on this, i  changed to copy destination syntax and occur error as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean be whole records. If you copy the whole workbook with .Cells.Copy() you have to paste it to cell(A1) on the target sheet Maybe you want .UsedRangeCopy.

Comment: Whole records means all records in that sheet, could you assists to show me where to change the code?

Comment: Yes but all the records means all 1,0485,576 rows which if you paste into the target destination sheet will overwrite any existing. If you want to do that use Destination:=oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

Comment: Oh, but destination will be different cells, thats why i define the range in destination, could you assists me? Should i change .cells.copy to another?

Comment: If you use .UsedRangeCopy instead of .Cells.Copy you should get all the records that have values. Then you can paste in the Destination you have. The problem might be if the used range starts in a column other than A which is where your destination is. Would that be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .Cells.Copy() which is every cell on the sheet, the destination has to be Range("A1") otherwise there is not enough room for the copied cells. I assume you want to only copy used rows in which case try

```
Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range, targetRow As Long

rngSource = oWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
With oWorkbookOri.Sheets(1)
    targetRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
    rngTarget = .cells(targetRow, rngSource.Column)
End With

rngSource.Copy(rngTarget)
MsgBox("Copied " & rngSource.Address & " to " & rngTarget.Address, vbInformation)
```

Comment: Okay, but destination i need to paste is different cell because there is previous data in A1, i cant overwrite it, could you advice?

Answer (score 0):

I try to amend below code

From

```
oWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy(Destination:=oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A" & oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1))
```

To

```
oWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy(Destination:=oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A" & oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1))
```

It still having error as mentioned

> "Copy method of Range class failed".

Comment: Do you get the error if you fix the range like oWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A10000") ?

Comment: Put  MsgBox(oWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address) before the copy and tell me what the range is.

Comment: This is what it display> $A$2:$U$7

Comment: Ok repeat using the other workbook MsgBox(oWorkbookOri.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address)

Comment: This is what display> $A$1:$U$4

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, hope you can assists me on it.

Comment: Can you write a small program that I can run and reproduce the problem. For me that line works. Did you try the code I wrote ?

Comment: Do you mean this line? oWorkBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A10000"), yes i did try this line but it occur error i mentioned just now

Comment: No I meant the 8 lines in my answer where the source and target ranges are defined before using copy. Is there anything special about these 2 sheets formatting, formulas, links, protection etc or are they plain sheets ?

Comment: Hi, I did try 8 lines as provided by yours when it reach to rngSource.Copy(rngTarget), it mentioned Copy method of Range class failed. 

Yes, there is formatting in 2 sheets eg percentage format, but without formulas, links, protection

rngSource = $A$3:$U$11
rngTarget = $A$5

Hope you can assists me~ Thanks alot

Comment: Try `Range("A3:U11").Copy Range("A5")`

Comment: Hi, i did tried it, it mentioned Copy method of Range class failed. 

This my code oWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A3:U11").Copy(oWorkBookOri.Sheets(1).Range("A5"))

Unsure where it went wrong. However, range need to be flexible as different number of records for some file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll hereby attached screenshot of source and target for better understanding. This is one of the example file, as different file have different rows of records and columns. Hence, need to make the range become flexible. Target to paste will required leave a blank row before paste it

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Grin.png)

[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpuVU.png)

Could it be the issue came from below code? as Source and Target display correct range

```
rngSource.Copy(rngTarget)
```

Appreciate it.